# How to calculate the interval in business day and the whole interval

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following data:

| entity_id | phase | old_phase | time | next_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 'Log' | null | 1654781946989 | 1654781949732 |
| 1 | 'Approve' | 'Log' | 1654781949732 | 1654781952676 |
| 1 | 'Fulfill' | 'Approve' | 1654781952676 | 1677506971778 |
| 1 | 'Accept' | 'Fulfill' | 1677506971778 | 1677518742552 |
| 1 | 'Review' | 'Accept' | 1677518742552 | 1678097845979 |
| 1 | 'Fulfill' | 'Review' | 1678097845979 | 1678097847325 |
| 1 | 'Accept' | 'Fulfill' | 1678097847325 | 1678097977816 |
| 1 | 'Review' | 'Accept' | 1678097977816 | null |
| 2 | 'Log' | null | 1645088036633 | 1645088043676 |
| 2 | 'Approve' | 'Log' | 1645088043676 | 1645088047318 |
| 2 | 'Fulfill' | 'Approve' | 1645088047318 | 1677500808099 |
| 2 | 'Close' | 'Fulfill' | 1677500808099 | null |

`time` and `next_time` are expressed as unix timestamp in milliseconds.

The goal is to calculate the sum of duration for each `entity_id` of each `Fulfill` phase.

My database is read only so I can't create function.

Expected result should be like :

| entity_id | Duration (excluding saturday and sunday) | Duration full |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 186 days 22 hours 30 minutes 21 seconds | {"months":8,"days":22,"hours":22,"minutes":30,"seconds":21} |
| 2 | 267 days 3 hours 32 minutes 41 seconds | {"years":1,"days":15,"hours":3,"minutes":32,"seconds":41} |

Current output :

| entity_id | Duration (excluding saturday and sunday) | Duration full |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 186 days 22 hours 30 minutes 19 seconds | {"months":8,"days":22,"hours":22,"minutes":30,"seconds":19} |
| 1 | -76 days 0 hours 0 minutes 2 seconds | {"seconds":2} |
| 2 | 267 days 3 hours 32 minutes 41 seconds | {"years":1,"days":15,"hours":3,"minutes":32,"seconds":41} |

If there is `2 Fulfill` phase on `1 entity_id`, the output isn't correct.

My SQL request :

```
WITH temp2 AS (
    SELECT
        entity_id,
        old_phase,
        phase,
        time,
        next_time,
        to_timestamp(to_char(to_timestamp("time"/1000.0) at time zone 'Europe/Paris', 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS'), 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS') at time zone 'Europe/Paris' AS "TIME 2",
        to_timestamp(to_char(to_timestamp("next_time"/1000.0) at time zone 'Europe/Paris', 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS'), 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS') at time zone 'Europe/Paris'AS "NEXT TIME 2",
        ((next_time - time)/1000.0) AS DIFF
    FROM 
        tbl_history
    WHERE phase = 'Fulfill'
),parms (entity_id, start_date, end_date) AS
(
    SELECT 
        entity_id,
        "TIME 2"::timestamp,
        "NEXT TIME 2"::timestamp
    FROM 
        temp2
), weekend_days (entity_id, wkend) AS 
(
    SELECT 
        entity_id,
        SUM(case when extract(isodow from d) in (6, 7) then 1 else 0 end) 
    FROM 
        parms
    CROSS JOIN 
        generate_series(start_date, end_date, interval '1 day') dn(d)
    GROUP BY entity_id
)

SELECT 
    entity_id,
    CONCAT(
        extract(day from diff), ' days ', 
        extract( hours from diff)   , ' hours ', 
        extract( minutes from diff) , ' minutes ', 
        extract( seconds from diff)::int , ' seconds '
    ) AS "Duration (excluding saturday and sunday)",
    justify_interval(end_date::timestamp - start_date::timestamp) AS "Duration full"
FROM (
    SELECT 
        start_date,
        end_date,
        entity_id,
        (end_date-start_date) - (wkend * interval '1 day') AS diff
    FROM parms 
    JOIN weekend_days USING(entity_id)
) sq;
```

Demo : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ujJe2t9CYLhoRm23RAbSbv/2

How can I calculate the full duration of the Fulfill phase of each entity_id (with and without business day) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the `sum`s of the time intervals (including `justify_interval`) for each `entity_id`, find the total number of weekends between all intervals of `entity_id`, and then join the results, subtracting the number of weekends from the total sum interval:

```sql
with cte as (
   select t.*, to_timestamp(to_char(to_timestamp(t.time/1000.0) at time zone 'Europe/Paris', 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS'), 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS') at time zone 'Europe/Paris' s,
    to_timestamp(to_char(to_timestamp(t.next_time/1000.0) at time zone 'Europe/Paris', 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS'), 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS') at time zone 'Europe/Paris' e
   from tbl_history t
),
dt_diff as (
   select t.entity_id, t.phase, sum(t.e - t.s) dr, sum(justify_interval(t.e - t.s)) dt 
   from cte t where t.phase = 'Fulfill' group by t.entity_id, t.phase
),
weekends as (
  select t.entity_id, t.phase, sum(case when extract(dow from v) in (0, 6) then 1 else 0 end) wt 
  from cte t cross join generate_series(t.s, t.e, interval '1 day') v  
  where t.phase = 'Fulfill' group by t.entity_id, t.phase
)
select t1.entity_id, t1.dr - make_interval(days => w.wt::int) "Duration (excluding saturday and sunday)", 
   (select jsonb_object_agg(d.key, d.value) from jsonb_each(
      jsonb_build_object('years', extract(years from t1.dt), 
       'months', extract(months from t1.dt), 
       'days', extract(days from t1.dt), 
       'hours', extract(hours from t1.dt), 
       'minutes', extract(minutes from t1.dt), 
       'seconds', extract(seconds from t1.dt))) d where d.value::int > 0) "Duration full"
from dt_diff t1 join weekends w on w.entity_id = t1.entity_id
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tRZ5aU-h)

Comment: I think the full duration isn't correct, For ex: the first row result has `"days":186` excluding saturday and sunday but in full duration the result is `"days":22`

Comment: @executable The full duration JSON includes the number of months, which reduces the amount of total days, per your example: `{"days": 22, "hours": 23, "months": 8, "minutes": 30, "seconds": 21.000000}`